# I cant figure out the read part of the Python program. Please assist

Tags: python

Write:

```
def main():

    import random

    #Open a file named numbers.txt.
    myfile = open('numbers.txt', 'w')

    file_size= random.randint(4,7)


    #Produce the numbers
    for i in range(file_size):
        k = random.randrange(5,19,2)



        #Write as many random intergers as the user request in the range of 5-19 on one line
        #to the file.
        myfile.write(str(num) + ' ')

    #Close the file.
    myfile.close()
    print('File Saved')

#Call the main function
main()
```

Read: How do i get the read coding to display the random numbers and also provide the sum?

```
def main():


    import random

  #Open a file named numbers.txt.
    myfile = open('numbers.txt', 'r')

    #Read/process the file's contents.
    file_contents = myfile.read()
    numbers = file_contents.split(" ")
    odd = 0
    num = int(file_contents)
    for file_contents in numbers:
     odd += num

    #Close the file.
    myfile.close()

    #Print out integer totals

    print('The total of the odd intergers is: ', odd)
```

Comment: This is riddled with issues well beyond the nebulous scope of the asked question. Have you run any of this? What is the output?

Comment: i fixed the write code but am still struggling with the read. see below.

Comment: def main():

    import random

    #Open a file named numbers.txt.
    myfile = open('numbers.txt', 'w')
    
    
    file_size=random.randint(4,7)

    #Produce the numbers
    for count in range(file_size):
        num = float(random.randrange(5,19,2))

    myfile.write(str(num) + ' '))
    
        

    #Close the file.
    myfile.close()
    print('File Saved')

#Call the main function
main()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to write every number into the file, therefore, you need to include it within the for loop:

```
#Produce the numbers
for count in range(file_size):
    num = random.randrange(5,19,2)
    myfile.write(str(num) + ' ')
```

When processing the numbers in, you're on the right track, but you've got it out of order:

```
numbers_as_strings = file_contents.split(" ")[:-1]
odd = 0
```

numbers is a list of strings representing each number, we want to iterate through them and do something for each of them. You may wonder why I added `[:-1]`? Because we made a string like `"1 2 3 4 5 "` See the last space? when you `split()` that, you'll get `"1","2","3","4","5",""`, and we don't want the last empty string `""`.

```
for number_as_string in numbers_as_strings:
    odd += int(number_as_string)
```

finally, to print the list of numbers there is a nice way of doing that built into python, `join()`. `' '.join()` says put all these together, and put that space (`' '`) between them.

```
print(' '.join(numbers_as_strings))
```